# Bootstrap .well + .pull-right issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with bootstraps `pull-right` class.
When I have a floated element inside a `.well` the well doesn't count the floated element into its size. So the element (in my case a `<button>` is half outside of the div.

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this.

Code if anyone wonders:

```
<div class="well">
<h5>TEXT</h5>
<p><img src="img/src.png" class="pull-right" alt=""/>Genere illum vero diam ille sui coniungens in lucem in. Cyrenaeam plus plorantes abscederem assignato ipsum ait mea vero non ait est amet coram me testatur in!</p>
<button class="btn btn-metro pull-right">text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why was this closed as too localized? I've got exactly the same issue and found this very useful...

Comment: x2. Found this via google and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I have solved the problem by clearing the floats. It's simple just add the class `.clearfix` to the `.well`.

As Alexis said in the comments, the div should look like this:

```
<div class="well clearfix">
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot, but it take me a while to understand what you mean, i'm a pretty noob at css, just for clearing for other people `class="well clearfix"`

Comment: First time in my life where I can actually see the working and need for clearfix. Nicely done

Answer (score 1):

In [Boostrap pull-right causing element overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667427/boostrap-pull-right-causing-element-overlap) described the way without using `.clearfix`:

```
<div class="text-right">
  <button class="btn btn-metro">text</button>
</div>
```