# Bootstrap pull-right causing element overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a single button positioned above a list, but with the button to the right.

When I add the pull-right class to the button (or a containing div) the button is then overlapped by the list.

```
<div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Something something 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Something something 2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Something something 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulbau/384YH/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should add the `pull-right` class to the `button` element instead and then add a clearfix to the parent element. In doing so, the `div` won't collapse upon itself.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPU9T/)

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add</button>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, since the `button` is an `inline-block` level element, you could avoid floating it and use `text-align:right` instead. Just add the class `text-right` to the parent. You no longer need the clearfix because the `button` element isn't being removed from the document flow.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5pCSw/)

```
<div class="text-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</div>
```